# CRON service not working correctly when run automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, cpanel

I'm using cPanel to run a CRON JOB on my website every night at midnight.

```
/usr/bin/wget http://domain.com?iscron=yes&token=jf094h0werg&service=close
```

I have an email that gets sent out from the CRON Daemon, that tells me cPanel executed the CRON JOB. This fires at midnight, without any problems.

I have another email setup IN the CRON job, that lets me know that the service actually executed. This does NOT get sent at midnight. (Like I would expect.)

None of the CRON actions seem to run, when the CRON JOB gets launched automatically. However, when I run the CRON JOB manually, everything works perfectly.

does someone with a bit more experience have any idea why this would be happening?

tl;dr - CRON JOB isn't executing automatically, but works perfectly when run manually.

Comment: Did you ask to server provider technical team?

Comment: I had a developer building the site for me. He and his team were stumped. I've talked to my server admins, and they assure me the CRON is running at midnight. (The Daemon email confirms that.) 

Basically, no one can tell me why the actions aren't executing, only that it looks like the service is being fired at midnight.

Comment: I see , Then you should check if your developer has added any code integration with that cron job. That code may be creating problem and need to correct.

Comment: But wouldn't those problems show up when running the CRON manually? I would think a problem with the code would cause manual executions to fail too, right?

Comment: Manually means from cron manager in cpanel , right?

Comment: No, sorry. Manually means I copy the URL in the CRON JOB, and paste it in my browser.

http://domain.com?iscron=yes&token=jf094h0werg&service=close

Comment: I see then it is difficult to find without checking from all aspects. Any logs in error log?

Comment: The script isn't failing during execution, not getting to the end where it mails completion?

Comment: The script doesn't fail when I run it from my browser, though I can't be sure it's not failing when running automatically. (Not sure why it would)

When cPanel runs the CRON, I don't get the email I've placed in the file to tell me everything executed correctly, however I do when I run it manually.

Comment: @MikeEstes have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Maybe the code itself has something that check the user agent and respond differently if you access it from the browser than from the command line wget command. It's a far shot but worth checking

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the cron like this:

```
wget --spider http://your_domain.tld?iscron=yes&token=jf094h0werg&service=close
```

Wget basically tries to download the content from the provided link so you'll have to instruct wget to act as a spider and execute URL not downloading it.